# Training Dialogflow agent via API V2

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to automate training the agent and I'm using the V2 API.
When I want to add a new example training phrase to an existing intent, I think I need to update the intent by using this API call: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/patch

But if I call that API with an intent that only has the one new training phrase it will delete all the existing ones. So I probably need to first get the contents of the intent. I tried to do it with this API call: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents/get

But there the problem is that the intent that is returned does not contain training phrases at all.

Can anyone help me to add training phrases via the V2 API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the Dialogflow support I got the answer that I was missing the intentView argument from my get intent call and that's why the training phrases were not visible. Now it returns them and I can train the agent!

[image: Adding intent view argument]

Comment: May I ask you what programming language are you using? If you're using Java, may I ask you how do you set the IntentView to get also the training phrases list?

Comment: I’m using JavaScript but my question was language agnostic since I just wanted to know how to use the API. You should look for an answer to how to pass query parameters in Java.

Comment: @mattipet : M facing the same issue. I've trained the intent via Dialogflow console, and tried training the same intent with only one training phrase via curl. It gave "success" 200, but now on console, I could neither see my old training phrases, nor the new that i gave via curl. can u help in that? Have i lost all the old training sets for that Intent???

Comment: I got my previous mistake. Now getting my new training phrases for intent (on console), but the old ones are still missing. Below is my curl command, appreciate your help.

`curl -X PUT \
'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/intents/<id>?v=20150910' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer <dev-token>' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
 "auto": true,
 "name": "dislike_reaction",
 "userSays": [{
   "data": [{
    "text": "once more"
   }]
  },
  {
   "data": [{
    "text": "1 more"
   }]
  }
 ],
 "webhookForSlotFilling": false,
 "webhookUsed": false
}'`

Comment: I think you are calling the detectIntent endpoint and that does not return the training phases AFAIK. The way I'm calling the getIntent is `curl -X GET "https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2beta1/projects/<project-id>/agent/intents/<intent-id>?intentView=INTENT_VIEW_FULL" -H "Authorization: Bearer <dev-token>"`

Comment: @mattipet I am trying to do the same from the node js. Just want to check if I am passing the values properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038315/upload-intent-function-dialogflow-v2/52067972

Comment: @AshishSinghRawat Sorry I looked at your question but I am not sure what is causing your problem. Probably something with the authorization and permissions but I can only guess.

Comment: @mattipet- Thanks for posting the answer and replying  Urvashi's question.  I have a very silly question - how  do you get the dev-token?  Can I run the curl from my Mac's local shell?  I have been going crazy to make it work but found the Dialogflow docs to be very confusing.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this. Took me hours to find why this is happening