# Upload Intent function Dialogflow V2

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I am trying to develop an API to upload the intent to `Dialogflow` V2. I have tried below snippet, which it is not working however if trying to communicate with `Dialogflow` it does work (detect intent)and does get a reply from the `Dialogflow` for queries.

**PERMISSION**

I AM & ADMIN > SERVICE ACCOUNTS > DIALOGFLOW ADMIN

**ERROR**

> Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: IAM permission 'dialogflow.entityTypes.create' on 'projects/dexter-47332/agent' denied.

**BLOGS/ REFERENCES**

1. [Dialogflow easy way for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50545943/dialogflow-easy-way-for-authorization)
2. https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client-v2/blob/master/samples/resource.js#L26
3. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow
4. https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/
5. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

```js
//------- keys.json (test 1)

{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mybot",
  "private_key_id": "123456asd",
  "private_key": "YOURKEY",
  "client_email": "yourID@mybot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "098091234",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/yourID%40mybot.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}


//--------------------- ** (test 2) ** ---------

let privateKey = 'key';
let clientEmail = "email";

let config = {
  credentials: {
    private_key: privateKey,
    client_email: clientEmail
  }
}

function createEntityTypes(projectId) {
  // [START dialogflow_create_entity]
  // Imports the Dialogflow library
  const dialogflow = require('dialogflow');

  // ******** Instantiates clients (Test 1)********
  const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient({
    'keyFilename': './keys.json'
  });
  const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient({
    'keyFilename': './keys.json'
  });

  // ******** Instantiates clients (Test 2)********
  const entityTypesClient = new dialogflow.EntityTypesClient(config);
  const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient(config);


  // The path to the agent the created entity type belongs to.
  const agentPath = intentsClient.projectAgentPath(projectId);

  const promises = [];

  // Create an entity type named "size", with possible values of small, medium
  // and large and some synonyms.
  const sizeRequest = {
    parent: agentPath,
    entityType: {
      displayName: 'test',
      kind: 'KIND_MAP',
      autoExpansionMode: 'AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_UNSPECIFIED',
      entities: [{
          value: 'small',
          synonyms: ['small', 'petit']
        },
        {
          value: 'medium',
          synonyms: ['medium']
        },
        {
          value: 'large',
          synonyms: ['large', 'big']
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  promises.push(
    entityTypesClient
    .createEntityType(sizeRequest)
    .then(responses => {
      console.log('Created size entity type:');
      logEntityType(responses[0]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Failed to create size entity type ----->:', err);
    })
  );
}

createEntityTypes(projectId);
```

Comment: You have to add the permission in IAM for `client_email`  which you are sending as a part of credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT(JSON Web Tokens) for authenticating with service accounts like in this [example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-bike-shop-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js)

```
 const serviceAccount = { };    // JSON key contents {"type": "service_account",...

 const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
 email: serviceAccount.client_email,
 key: serviceAccount.private_key,
 scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
});
```

For more OAuth2.0 scopes for Google APIs you can see the full list [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. I corrected it by deleting the current service account and creating a new one and selected the "owner" option for the role.

Answer (score 0):

The associated service-account has to have the role "Dialogflow API Admin" to be able to create intents and entities.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must provide a name parameter there in the sizeRequest and make it equal to an empty string.

Take a look at the code snippet.

```
    let request = {
        parent: `projects/${PROJECID}/agent`,
        entityType: {
            name: '',
            autoExpansionMode: 'AUTO_EXPANSION_MODE_DEFAULT',
            displayName: 'size_type',
            enableFuzzyExtraction: false,
            entities: [
                {
                    value: 'Big',
                    synonyms: ['big', 'large', 'huge']
                },
                {
                    value: 'Medium',
                    synonyms: ['medium', 'not big']
                }
            ],
            kind: 'KIND_MAP'
        },
        languageCode: 'en'
};
```

Please let me know if this helps.